# TFS check-in: Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy. Error loading the Changeset Comments Policy policy

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I modified file via Visual Studio and now I'll want to check in changes via power-shell

> \TF.exe checkin "C:\Users\xxx\Source\Workspaces\Tests\xxx\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" /comment:"Version 1.1.1.1" /noprompt /force

I'm using this command and everything worked fine, but when I created new project in other collection then I started receiving errors like this:

> TF10139: The following check-in policies have not been satisfied:
> Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy. Error loading the Changeset Comments Policy policy (The policy assembly '
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.ChangesetComments, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
> =b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered.). Installation instructions:

> No files checked in.

What may cause that? I guess it may be project/collection related, but idk.

I have `TF.exe` from Visual Studio 2019, one of the latest patches

I've seen this, but I don't see how this solution relates to my problem

[TF10139 Error:Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy for tf checkin command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168407/tf10139-errorinternal-error-in-changeset-comments-policy-for-tf-checkin-command)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try re-registering the Changeset Comments policy by following below steps:

Go to the Team project setting--> Source Control-->Remove the Changeset Comments policy from check-in policy--> re-add it.

[image]

You can also check out the answers to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203112/internal-error-in-changeset-comments-policy-after-updating-vs2015-to-update-1).

Comment: Unfortunely it didn't solve my problem. For now I just disabled that check

Answer (score 0):

I've spent literally 7 hours trying to figure out how to fix this issue and I've finally managed to fix it. Steps I took to get it working:

- Install visual studio 2015 and install the Teams Foundation server
  power tools 2015 addon
- configure git tfs to run in 32-bit mode (run enable_checkin_policies_support in the git-tfs installation folder (CorFlags.exe git-tfs.exe /32BITPREF+ /nologo))
- configure the git tfs to run the correct visual studio version (it runs latest by default, you can check this by running `git tfs version` (mine was 16.0.0.0 -> it needs to be 14.0.0.0 to use vs2015). You can do this by setting a GIT_TFS_CLIENT environment variable ([use 2015 as value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxPd3.png))